# Mark a position in eclipse text editor?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have two questions:

1. While editing a source file, it's very convenient to be able to label the current position of cursor and then jump to it later by somehow calling that label. I VIM, there is the marking notion, but I'm not aware of such possibility in Eclipse text editor.
2. Is there any way in Eclipse to add a portion of the code to the outline window, such that you can easily jump to that part when you click on it? I know that for java source-code, almost all variables and functions are shown there, but what if I have a html/javascript code, in which I'm using jquery functions, and the outline doesn't show these functions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont have any direct answers for your question.

May be you are looking for the following eclipse features.

1. Eclipse supports bookmarks, you may use that feature. Also CTRL + Q will go back to the last edited location.
2. You may be able to get this using the Mylyn, which is packaged along with eclipse by default. Implements the notion of a Task focussed IDE ( RECOMMENDED)

Comment: Hey Script Runner!
I got both of my questions answered by eclipse bookmarks! Great!

Thanks!